# How to get max date time value in data and get respective data

Tags: datetime, max

The input looks like:

```
9999993612,10/Feb/2016:19:04:16
9999993612,10/Feb/2016:19:04:15
9999993612,10/Feb/2016:19:04:09
9999993612,10/Feb/2016:01:31:47
9999993612,10/Feb/2016:01:31:46
9999993612,10/Feb/2016:01:31:43
```

We need output.

```
9999993612,10/Feb/2016:19:04:16
```

using linux command.

Comment: so what have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Note that StackOverflow is not a free code writing service

Answer (score 0):

**** It's working fine**********

awk 'BEGIN{FS=","; print "NO time"} NR!=1 {a[$1]++;b[$1]=$2}END{for (i in a) printf("%s %s \n" ,i, b[i])} ' FILENAME